# Probabilities, diffusion-limited aggregation

Tags: probability

Firstly, sorry for my bad english.

We consider a sequence $A_n$ of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ (d is the dimension), which increase according to the following property : at the step n, a particle is thrown at the origin and is moving according to a random walk (if $d=1$, the probabilities to go at the left or at the right are 1/2 ; if $d = 2$, the probabilities to go North, South, West or East are 1/4).

The particle is moving until it comes out of $A_n$ in a point $X_{n+1}$. We define : $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup X_n$.

The model is initialized with $A_1=\{0\}$. $A_n$ is called aggregate at step n. We consider $d = 1$.

I can understand that :

If $A_1 = \{0\}$, then $A_2 = \{0,1\}$ with probability $1/2$, or $A_2 = \{-1,0\}$ with probability $1/2$. Indeed, the particle comes out of $A_1$ at the point $1$ or $-1$.

If $A_2 = \{0,1\}$, $A_3 = \{0,1,2\}$ or $A_3 = \{-1,0,1\}$. If $A_2 = \{-1,0\}$, $A_3 = \{-1,0,2\}$ or $A_3 = \{-2,-1,0\}$ (always with probability $1/2$).

etc

And we note $A_n = \{L_n, ..., R_n\}$ with $L_n$ and $R_n$ are respectively the leftmost and the rightmost points of the aggregate. We note $Z_n = R_n + L_n$. How we find 'again' $L_n$ and $R_n$ from $Z_n$ ?

I think but I'm not sure that, for example with $A_2$, $L_2 = -1$ and $R_2 = 1$, is it ? And for $A_3$, $L_3 = -2$ and $R_3 = 2$ ?

Someone could help me for the two previous questions ? Thank you in advance.

Edit : I finally found the answer (in the comments) !

Comment: I managed to answer ! :) $R_n = \frac{Z_n+(n-1)}{2}$ and $L_n = \frac{Z_n - (n-1)}{2}$