# Subsets in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, particle, order of magnitude

Tags: probability, statistics

I hope I'm in the good section, and sorry for my bad english.

Let $B_n$ a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. A particle is thrown at the origin and is moving until it comes out of $B_n$ in a point $X$. We initialize $B_1 = \{0\}$ and $B_{n+1} = B_n \cup X$.

The probability of the particle to go at North, at South, at East or at West is $1/4$ for each direction.

We underline $B_n$ is of volume $n$. If we consider that $B_n$ grows steadily, at what distance from the origin (in order of magnitude) is the $n^{th}$ point added ?

I think it's easy but I don't see how to do it at all. Someone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for the range of possible values?

Comment: Yes, that's it ! :)

Comment: I don't think it's easy. I believe this is a known probability model. I will try to remember the name

Comment: @quasi: I think you've misunderstood the question. I believe the OP is asking: suppose you drop in a particle; it bounces around the existing cluster until it finds an unoccupied vertex. What can be said about the order of magnitude of distance of the $n$th particle's resting place from the origin?

Comment: @anthonyquas: The question never mentioned expectation, and the OP seemed to agree when I asked if all that was needed was the range of possible values. I'm guessing this is just a HW problem, but at what level, I'm not sure. Since expected distance is too hard (except to approximate via simulation), I assumed a much simpler question. The OP did very little by way of clarification.

Comment: @quasi: she did ask "at what distance from the origin is the $n$th point added"? and she further clarified that she was interested in the order of magnitude. I suspect her response to your initial question was a language issue.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2264097/probabilities-diffusion-limited-aggregation. Now apparently I don't need to remember the name of the process as the poster already knows it... grrr...

Comment: @anthonyquas: Ok, I agree, "order of magnitude" suggests expected distance is the objective, but I would be surprised (pleasantly surprised) if there's a closed form.

Comment: The question is given as it ! We would like to know the distance in order of magnitude the n-th point is added if $B_n$ grows steadily, but I don't know how to do it... This is the model of internal diffusion limited aggregation in dimension $2$. For my other subject, I finally found the answer and left it in comments !